# Can't install McAfeeVSEForLinux on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, antivirus

I'm trying to install McAfeeVSEForLinux agent on Ubuntu 20.04.
While following McAfee's install instructions:

```
sudo dpkg -i MFErt.i686.deb
sudo dpkg -i MFEcma.i686.deb
```

These two commands execute successfully but but at the next one

```
sudo bash McAfeeVSEForLinux<version>-installer
```

I'm getting this error

```
ldconfig: loadlocale.c:129: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
/home/adminps1/Desktop/McAfee/McAfeeVSEForLinux-2.0.3.29216-installer: line 778:  3968 Aborted                 (core dumped) $INSTALLDIR/libexec/ldconfig -f ${DEFAULT_LINKER_CONFIG} -C ${DYNAMIC_LINKER_CACHE}
/opt/NAI/LinuxShield/libexec/openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to generate key
<13>May 23 20:03:47 adminps1: vsel-installer: failed to install the McAfeeVSEForLinux certificate
ldconfig: loadlocale.c:129: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
/home/adminps1/Desktop/McAfee/McAfeeVSEForLinux-2.0.3.29216-installer: line 180:  3986 Aborted                 (core dumped) $installDir/libexec/ldconfig -f ${DEFAULT_LINKER_CONFIG} -C ${DYNAMIC_LINKER_CACHE}
```

Do anyone have idea what is going on here?

Comment: Do you realize you're installing a 32 bit app on a 64 bit OS? You'll have to install all the 32 bit libraries as well... I don't understand what you need a virus scanner for- on linux

Comment: Hello Nikola. Usually you do not need Anti-virus softwares/scanners on Ubuntu. Maybe you can ask another question or look for an existing answer that suggests an alternative to McAfee. Those will get installed and do the job better than this one.

Comment: @thewebjackal The version OP installing is actually an enterprise set of protection tools and not some random freeware. No need to degrade mcafee. I've been working with mcafee enterprise protection for years now and they offer nice quality protection tools and software of all layers when it comes to endpoint. OP is just trying to install an end of life version that is not suitable for upper versions of Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Mcafee VSE is end of life as of January 2018, and end of enterprise support as of the end of 2019 (excluded special cases).
Organisations were asked to upgrade to endpoint protection for over 3 years now.
Even if you succeed with your installation, it will have major flaws and no support.

VSE is not officially supported for ubuntu 20.04 (and 18.04 it seems) as mcafee [documentation states](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB75270).
So I'm not sure they will even address an opened case regarding VSE now.
Organisations were asked to update to endpoint security for linux as [documented here](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB87073).

Tip: Last time I used my grant number, I couldn't even find VSE available for download from their site. Though if you hold an enterprise support, try reaching your agent for full details or solutions.

Comment: These are all commands I used while installing:
1. sudo dpkg -i MFErt.i686.deb